# How do I disable the 'allowedMethods' mechanism for my Grails controller

Tags: grails

I'm developing a small grails app and I am having a great deal of difficulty with the delete action. In particular, I keep getting a

```
405-The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

message.

I've tried removing the

```
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
```

line from my controller but I still get the error.

Is there a way to disable the allowed methods mechanism?

Comment: You might want to verify in your UrlMapping class, since you can define them there aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `allowedMethods` map (or individual entries) is the way to do this. There are no default checks for this in Grails. Try running `grails clean` and restarting - it may be that you need a full recompile for the change to take effect.